# SQL to find linking column across tables without foreign keys

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to find table links using duplicate column names. Say i have the following tables

T1:

```
| Prod_ID | Cust_Id | Value |
| P1      | C1      | 1     |
| P2      | C2      | 2     |
| P3      | C3      | 3     |
| P4      | C4      | 4     |
| P5      | C5      | 5     |
```

T2:

```
| Prod_ID | Prod_Num |
| P1      | PN1      |
| P2      | PN2      |
| P3      | PN3      |
| P4      | PN4      |
| P5      | PN5      |
```

I rely on system tables to fetch table information. The data looks like

```
| tabname | colname  |
| T1      | Prod_ID  |
| T1      | Cust_Id  |
| T1      | Value    |
| T2      | Prod_ID  |
| T2      | Prod_Num |
| T3      | ....     |
```

If i want to find all tables with columns **Prod_ID** and **Cust_ID**, i could do the same using

```
SELECT tabname, count(*)
FROM syscat.columns
WHERE colname IN ('Prod_ID', 'Cust_Id') 
GROUP BY tabname
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Now, when i want to find how two columns across tables are linked, the query is getting complex.

For example: To find how **Cust_Id** and **Prod_Num** are linked, the expected output would be something like

```
| tabname | colname  |
| T1      | Cust_id  |
| T1      | Prod_id  |
| T2      | Prod_id  |
| T2      | Prod_Num |
```

Suggesting that Prod_Id is contained in both tables and can be used to map Cust_Id and Prod_num. Is there a script for getting something like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use self-joins for that.

```
SELECT c1.tabname, c2.colname joinCol, c3.tabname
FROM syscat.columns c1
JOIN syscat.columns c2 ON c1.tabname = c2.tabname
JOIN syscat.columns c3 ON c3.tabname != c2.tabname and c3.colname = c2.colname
JOIN syscat.columns c4 ON c4.tabname = c3.tabname and c3.colname = c2.colname
WHERE c1.colname = 'Cust_Id' and c4.colname = 'Prod_Num'
```

The output is the following:

```
tabname joinCol  tabname
---------------------------
T1      Prod_id  T2
```

which means that table `t1` is joined with `t2` using `prod_id` (`cust_id` and `prod_num` are on the input, therefore there is no need to have them on the output)

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7860ea186a618a3e306af5b8187c5247) - it is SQL Server, however, `JOIN` will work in DB2 as well ;)